# 'NSString!' is not convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Tags: ios, swift

Code:

```
 var strCategIds = ""

    for(var i = 0; i < arrCateName.count; i++){
            var prCate:PropCategory = arrCateName.objectAtIndex(i) as! PropCategory
            if(prCate.bSelected == true){
                    strCategIds =  strCategIds + prCate.strCategoryId as! String!

            }
        }
```

What is this error meaning?I have spent lot of time on it.but no success.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
strCategIds + prCate.strCategoryId as! String!
```

is compiled as

```
(strCategIds + prCate.strCategoryId) as! String!
```

Instead, I think you should:

```
strCategIds + (prCate.strCategoryId as! String)
```